# Get the count for deleted records when using cascade delete constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server

When using ON DELETE CASCADE constraint and deleting a "master" record is there a way to get the count of "child" records deleted?

For example using these table:

```
CREATE TABLE Master ( ID INT PRIMARY KEY (ID))
GO

CREATE TABLE Child ( ID INT, MasterID INT)
GO

ALTER TABLE Child ADD CONSTRAINT FK_Child_Master FOREIGN KEY(MasterID)
REFERENCES Master (ID)
ON DELETE CASCADE
GO

INSERT INTO Master (ID) VALUES (1);

INSERT INTO Child ( ID, MasterID) VALUES (1,1),(2,1),(3,1),(4,1),(5,1);
```

Now if I delete the master record like this:

```
DELETE FROM Master WHERE ID = 1;

SELECT @@ROWCOUNT;
```

The 5 rows in the Child table and the 1 row in the Master table are all deleted but the result is 1. It only counts the records deleted from the master table.

Is there a way to capture the number of rows deleted from the child table or do I need delete from the child table first, get the count, then delete from the master?

Comment: These might be slight variations of what you're asking, but may also be helpful:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/14440045/1024832, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56542158/find-out-how-many-rows-that-will-be-deletedon-cascade-if-one-row-in-a-table-is

Comment: @Marc although user has tagged SQL Server, not Oracle.

Comment: Short answer is no. Slightly longer answer is - don't assume there is a single child table that will be affected. If you do assume this, then you might as well take responsibility for the deletion process rather than abdicating it to the database engine.

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can use a stored procedure to do this like

```
create procedure spDeleteRecords
@id int
begin
    select count(*) from child_table where id=@id
    delete from parent_table where id=@id
end
```