# Oracle on delete CASCADE showing count of rows deleted

Tags: oracle, cascading-deletes

I have a bunch of tables, which are joined by Foriegn keys. Based on those Foriegn keys if I delete a parent record all the children, grandchild….rows will be deleted. My setup works fine.

Is there a way to determine the number of rows deleted from each table with a query without coding the SELECT statement before and after the delete like I did in my test CASE below.

I tried using this but it only returns 1 for the parent row that was deleted.

```
begin
DELETE from parent where value = 'a';
dbms_output.put_line('count = '|| sql%rowcount);
    end;

I'm looking for an output similar to this:

Rows Deleted 
parent 1
child 3
grandchild
```

Below is my setup and test case.

```
create table parent (
  id NUMBER(10),
  value      varchar2(30),
constraint parent_pk primary key (id)
);

CREATE TABLE child
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint child_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT parent_child_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id)
REFERENCES parent(id)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);

CREATE TABLE grandchild
( id NUMBER(10) not null,
value NUMBER(10) not null,
constraint grandchild_pk primary key (id,value),
CONSTRAINT child_grandchild_fk
FOREIGN KEY (id,value)
REFERENCES child(id,value)
ON DELETE CASCADE
);


insert into parent values (1,'a');
insert into parent values (2,'b');
insert into parent values (3,'c');

insert into child  values (1,1);
insert into child  values (1,2);
insert into child  values (1,3);
insert into child  values (2,1);
insert into child  values (2,2);
insert into child  values (2,3);
insert into child  values (3,1);
insert into child  values (3,2);
insert into child  values (3,3);

insert into grandchild  values (1,1);
insert into grandchild  values (1,2);
insert into grandchild  values (1,3);
insert into grandchild  values (2,1);
insert into grandchild  values (2,2);
insert into grandchild  values (2,3);
insert into grandchild  values (3,1);
insert into grandchild  values (3,2);
insert into grandchild  values (3,3);


SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual


DELETE from parent where value = 'a';
PARENT_CNT    CHILD_CNT    GRANDCHILD_CNT
3    9    9

SELECT  (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   parent 
        ) AS parent_cnt,
       (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   child 
        ) AS child_cnt,
        (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM   grandchild
        ) AS grandchild_cnt
FROM    dual

PARENT_CNT    CHILD_CNT    GRANDCHILD_CNT
2    6    6
```

Here is a query that shows the relationships between tables, which I found. Can this query be expanded to help achieve my goal?

```
with f as (
        select constraint_name, table_name, r_constraint_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'R'
     ),
     p as (
        select constraint_name, table_name
        from   user_constraints
        where  constraint_type = 'P'
     ),
     j (child_table, f_key, parent_table, p_key) as (
        select f.table_name, f.constraint_name, p.table_name, f.r_constraint_name
        from   p join f on p.constraint_name = f.r_constraint_name
        union all
        select 'PARENT', (select constraint_name from p                                where table_name = 'PARENT'), null, null from dual
     )
select level as lvl, j.*
from j
start with parent_table is null
connect by nocycle parent_table = prior child_table
order by lvl, parent_table, child_table;

LVL    CHILD_TABLE    F_KEY    PARENT_TABLE    P_KEY
1    PARENT    PARENT_PK     -      - 
2    CHILD    PARENT_CHILD_FK    PARENT    PARENT_PK
3    GRANDCHILD    CHILD_GRANDCHILD_FK    CHILD    CHILD_PK
```

Happy holidays and thanks in advance to all who answer.

Comment: Simply, no.  can't do that

Comment: @OldProgrammer thanks for responding. Can you explain why. I would think code would be needed to traverse down the FK tables with perhaps a SELECT. I got the relationships figured out is there more information that would be needed?

Comment: you can do that to get the relationships, but how does that help you determine the number of rows deleted from each table?   Why does it matter?  What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: @OldProgrammer we had a case where an application issued a wrong query and wiped out many records when they should not have been. I argued against the delete CASCADE for this very reason. Needless to say a DBA spent 9 hours over the weekend restoring a DB. I was looking to prevent such catastrophes in the future by putting in a wrapper that says N number of tows will be deleted from.... are you sure you want to proceed.

Comment: Well now you know why many DBAs will not allow cascade, often a wise precaution. However, be very careful building a message for user to confirm. Unless they are familiar with the design they will typically respond no when system asks about deleting many rows (100s perhaps 1000s) when they just asked to delete 1. Of course they then complain to you that the system has a bug which wants to delete too many rows. Best option: do not use cascade delete.

Comment: @oldprogrammer FYI I found the following solution but I don't like the idea of putting all these triggers in place https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14439097/oracle-delete-statement-how-many-rows-have-been-deleted-by-cascade-delete